# Symfony 2 Missing File Error When They're Not

Tags: symfony, file-permissions, production-environment

I got my Symfony 2.3 project working through app.php in development. I then did a complete copy to my shared host sever (goDaddy). So far, all I get are blank pages. I've been working my way through the errors. My lastest execution generates 100+ errors in the php log of this type:

```
[09-Jul-2013 12:52:56 America/Los_Angeles] PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(/Volumes/Data RAID/htdocs/Symfony/src/Zetcho/AmColAnBundle/Resources/views/User/userSubNav.html.twig) [<a href='function.file-get-contents'>function.file-get-contents</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/content/.../Symfony/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Templating/Storage/FileStorage.php on line 32
```

Then I get one of theses

```
[09-Jul-2013 12:52:56 America/Los_Angeles] PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(/Volumes/Data RAID/htdocs/Symfony/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/TwigBundle/Resources/views/Exception/exception_full.html.twig) [<a href='function.file-get-contents'>function.file-get-contents</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/content/.../Symfony/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Loader/Filesystem.php on line 127
```

The ellipses are mine. I verified that the file that both files were was at the locations specified and that I could read it. The permissions on the files are 644. Could this be a permission problem? If so, what should they be set to?

Update: I set the permissions to 755 and got the same errors.

Update 2: I just noticed that the error is giving my development server directory path. Now I just have to figure out where to change it.

Update 3: It appears to be the cache. There is not command access to a goDaddy shared server that I know of so I just deleted all the files in app/cache/prod. I now get my html, but no  css. I use Assetic for images and css. I get the images.

Update 4: When I clicked on a link, the next page used the css file. When I went back to the first page, it used it as well. As I check out the pages, some of the images are missing. Could this be because the cache wasn't rebuilt correctly or completely?

Update 5: Fixed the last problem with missing images. There was a case mismatch between the reference and the image. I think I'm good now.

Comment: Are you sure the case of the letters is equal to the actual location? Most localhosts are case-insentive, while the hosts are case-sensitive

Comment: @WouterJ you were right about case sensitivity. It wasn't the main problem, but there were a few images with upper case file extensions.